# Replace part of a string from a specific character

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace

How would I go about replacing everything from the ? in the following string:

```
profile_photo.jpg?1491781969
```

using `str_replace` in PHP.

So this is removed: ?1491781969

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `strpos` to find the position of the '?' in your string.  Then pass that in as the 3rd (length) parameter of `substr` to get all the characters in the string from 0 through (length).

```
<?php
$str = 'profile_photo.jpg?1491781969';
echo substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '?'));
?>
```

Comment: Thanks @Ryan Tuosto, exactly what I was after. Works a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything after the ? using `explode`:

```
<?php
$string = "profile_photo.jpg?1491781969";
echo explode('?',$string)[0];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_replace` with mask `/?\d+/` instead.
`str_replace` does not look for patterns and you must specify the exact string value.